gitlab runner kubernetes spin up pod with multiple containers
Just like in k8s, we can spin up a pod with multiple containers (docker images) and we can share the volume, similar to this, can we achieve the similar in gitlab runner when spinning up a pod  with volume path shared between two containers.
Actually we are doing similar to this thread - Two Docker images in GitLab CI .yaml
However, we are processing more than 30GB of the data, thus, doing the "Two docker images in gitlab-ci" will eventually take lots of time to finish, hence checking if its possible to do in gitlab-runner in K8s and spin up a pod (with two containers and volume sharing enabled) so that we can cut down the time completion.
